# Why is the decay time of the scintilator pulse of the gamma rays longer than the decay time of neutrons?

Tags: experimental-physics

When you discriminate between neutrons and gamma rays (using a liquid scintillator) you use the fact that the pulse due to gamma rays have a longer decay time than the pulse due to neutrons. When you compare the tail end of the pulses you then get the discrimination. Why is the decay time of the pulse from the gamma rays longer than that of the neutron? What is the physical reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qualitatively:

A neutron decays into a proton an electron and a neutrino. Both the proton and the electron are highly ionizing in any medium. After the decay the energy of the charged particles will be  absorbed very fast and turned into photons. A gamma ray does not decay, and is not able to  ionize the way a charged particle can. It has to interact with the electric field of the medium, scatter electrons which can be detected, or nuclei which also can be detected. The probability for this to happen is lower, needing longer paths and  thus leading to longer scintillator decay times.